# AlertDialog buttons are stacking with fixed width in Xamarin Droid project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-alertdialog

For some reason when I add the "android:minWidth" line to styles.xml, it's stacking the buttons on top of one another. Without the line, the buttons look fine though. I'm just trying to fix the width of the alert dialog and keep everything else the same. Here's the basics of my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#2E82F7</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">700dp</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textSize">36dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>-->
</style>
```

And here's what my alerts look like [with the fixed width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtmuI.jpg) and [without the fixed width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOeYA.jpg). I'm fairly new to Xamarin Forms, so any help is greatly appreciated. This is a shared project and I'm just calling the .Droid project to create the AlertDialog because they are easier to customize (increased font size, etc.) than the shared DisplayAlert message.

EDIT: Here's the code I'm running from my Android class:

```
public async Task<bool> dispAlert(String title, String message, bool tablet, String btn1, String btn2)
    {
        bool val = false;
        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();

        //alert.SetTitle(title);
        if (tablet)
        {
            //message.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
            //Debug.WriteLine("message = "+message);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Sdk) >= 24)
            {
                alert.SetTitle(Html.FromHtml("<big><big><big>" + title + "</big></big></big>", 0));
            }
            else
            {
                alert.SetTitle(Html.FromHtml("<big><big><big>" + title + "</big></big></big>"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert.SetTitle(title);
        }

        //Debug.WriteLine("Android Build # = " + Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Sdk);

        //need to check for Android version # and if 24 or higher add ,0
        if (tablet)
        {
            message.Replace("\n","<br/>");
            //Debug.WriteLine("message = "+message);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Sdk) >= 24)
            {
                alert.SetMessage(Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + message + "</big></big>", 0));
            }
            else
            {
                alert.SetMessage(Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + message + "</big></big>"));
            }
        }else{
            alert.SetMessage(message);
        }


        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            if (tablet)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("set tablet buttons");
                if (Convert.ToInt32(Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Sdk) >= 24)
                {
                    alert.SetButton((int)(DialogButtonType.Positive), Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + btn1 + "</big></big>",0), (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        val = true;
                        waitHandle.Set();
                    });

                    if (btn2 != null)
                    {
                        alert.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + btn2 + "</big></big>",0), (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            val = false;
                            waitHandle.Set();
                        });                         
                    }
                }else{

                    alert.SetButton((int)(DialogButtonType.Positive), Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + btn1 + "</big></big>"), (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        val = true;
                        waitHandle.Set();
                    });
                    if (btn2 != null)
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine("message = <big><big>" + btn2 + "</big></big>");
                        alert.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, Html.FromHtml("<big><big>" + btn2 + "</big></big>"), (sender, e) =>
                        {
                          val = false;
                          waitHandle.Set();
                        });                         
                    }


                }
            }else{
                //Debug.WriteLine("set phone buttons");
                alert.SetButton((int)(DialogButtonType.Positive), btn1, (sender, e) =>
                {
                    val = true;
                    waitHandle.Set();
                });

                if (btn2 != null)
                {
                    alert.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, btn2, (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        val = false;
                        waitHandle.Set();
                    });
                }
            }

            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(new Action(async () =>
            {
                //alert.Window.SetLayout(1200, 1200);
                alert.Show();

            }));
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        });
        alert.Dispose();

        //alert.Show();

        return val;
    }
```

And here's the call I'm making to it:

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{
    ret = await DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().dispAlert("Measuring Result", "Do you want to save the result?<br/> " + message, true, "Yes", "No");
}
else
{
    ret = await DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().dispAlert("Measuring Result", "Do you want to save the result?\n " + message, false, "Yes", "No");
}
```

Comment: May be because you specify min width 700dp so it occupies the whole width of the screen and there is no space for the next button in the same line. Try to decrease let say to 100dp and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Nope, it still stacks them unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your issue, could you please give me more information? Is this the whole style you have? On which device are you testing your code?

Comment: Ok, I updated the post. And I'm testing on a Galaxy Tab S and a Galaxy S8+

Comment: @Ryan, used your code to tested again and again on different device, I am still not able to reproduce your issue, but I don't have a Galaxy Tab S or Galaxy S8+, maybe you could try other device which is not from Samsung. If it is the problem of Samsung's system, then I'm not capable to give any help.